# Argument length when folder or file contains spaces

Tags: c#, .net

I have registered file association in windows to open specific file types in application, so that when user double clicks the file it opens on my application exe.

I receive the file path from argument and opens it. But when either folder or file name contains spaces (some time more than one space), the argument length is more than 1 and i don't know how to parse them in to a single file path.
I don't have control over the argument being passed since windows passes those on double click to my application exe.

Sample file path: C:\Sample 1\file 1.rtf

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should quote the argument before it's passed in:

```
myapplication.exe "C:\Sample 1\file 1.rtf"
```

If we take a look at the association for `.sln` files for Visual Studio under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln\Shell\Open\Command`, we can see that the association quotes the filename:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe" "%1"
```

Your association with your program should do the same. Alternatively, you could join the arguments into a single string:

```
var path = string.Join(string.Empty, args);
```

This is less flexible, however. Especially if you need to pass multiple arguments.

Comment: You second option to double quote in registry value for the file name is the correct solution. First solution is not the case for me since it is windows that passes the argument and i can't use the last solution using the string join since it will remove the spaces and file path will be invalid. Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the filename in quotes.

```
applicationname.exe "C:\Sample 1\file 1.rtf"
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not the case for my issue. It is the windows that passes the argument not another program. John has the correct solution above.